# SVN File descriptor corruption

Tags: c, svn

I was looking at the source code of SVN and found this comment in the source code.

```
/* The following makes sure that file descriptors 0 (stdin), 1
   (stdout) and 2 (stderr) will not be "reused", because if
   e.g. file descriptor 2 would be reused when opening a file, a
   write to stderr would write to that file and most likely
   corrupt it. */
```

followed by this code:

```
if ((fstat(0, &st) == -1 && open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY) == -1) ||
    (fstat(1, &st) == -1 && open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY) == -1) ||
    (fstat(2, &st) == -1 && open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY) == -1))
  {
    if (error_stream)
      fprintf(error_stream, "%s: error: cannot open '/dev/null'\n",
              progname);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

I don't understand how "reusing" a file descriptor can corrupt a file. And how can you open a file with file descriptor 2 (stderr) ? And how opening a file can effect write to stderr ?

Comment: If code writes an error message to standard error but standard error is pointing at an SVN file and not at a terminal or something similar, then that SVN file will be corrupted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't understand how can standart error is pointing to a SVN file. Don't we use it as a output file descriptor. If we e.g. have a file descriptor open to a file like fopen and return a FP, how does that FP point to stderr. Is there a code that can demonstrate that ?

Comment: @Plimpus Yes I was looking there on my local copy of the svn repository. The thing is I don't understand how a file pointer can point to stderr. Like is this an issue when we fprintf to the screen that unix somehow understand the fprintf(stderr, ...) wrong and writes it to the lastest open file descriptor or something ?

Comment: @Zer0day the commit log message mentions the `svnadmin` utility. So I'm unsure if the code is relevant for client-side operations. Perhaps it's more for `svnadmin` and other admin utilities.

Comment: If you run `svn … 2>&-`, SVN is launched with no standard error (the `2>&-` means "close file descriptor 2").  Then the first file that is opened would be given file descriptor 2.  But `stderr` uses file descriptor 2, so any error message would go to the the file that was opened.  The write would fail if the file was open for reading and not writing, but otherwise, the error message would scribble where you didn't expect it to.  That's a bit different from `svn … 2>/dev/null` where standard error is redirected to `/dev/null`, or `svn … 2>/tmp/svn.log` where it goes to the named file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So anytime we use a file descriptor either with open() or close() this file descriptor will also be used for the next open() or close() operation right ? Are these open() and close() function from C standart library or linux close() and open() functions ? Also does this apply to other functions as well alongside open and close ?

Comment: The official rule is "`open()` — or any other similar file descriptor creating function, including `pipe()` — will use the lowest file descriptor number that is currently closed".  AFAIK, the only exceptions are `dup2()` (where you specify the file descriptor to use) and `fcntl(F_DUPFD, …)` (where you specify the lowest file descriptor number to use).  But if file descriptor 2 is closed (but 0 and 1 are open), then the first available file descriptor is 2 and that will be returned by `open()` or whichever colleague is called instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But we have to call fcntl for every file descriptor that we create after closing stderr if we want to open stderr again. Is there a global way of setting that ? So we woudn't have to call fcntl for every file descriptor ?

Comment: If you know that file descriptors 0, 1, 2 are open (because the C standard mandates that they should be, or because you checked early on), and the code in the application (SVN in this case) never closes any of those descriptors, then there's no need to continually check.  That is what the code you quote seems to do — use `/dev/null` with file descriptors 0, 1, 2 if they're not already open.  And that avoids the trouble.  POSIX specifies the behaviour I noted in [§2.14 File Descriptor Allocation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that I don't know about SVN-specific problems this code is designed to solve (it was committed more than 18 years ago). But I think that the below summary describes the potential problem at high level. So I assume that the part of code in question prevents this from happening:

> Longstanding Unix practice dictates that applications are started with
> the standard input, output, and error I/O streams on file descriptors
> 0, 1, and 2, respectively. The assumption that these file descriptors
> will be properly set up is so strong that most developers never think
> to check them. So interesting things can happen if an application is
> run with one or more of the standard file descriptors closed.
>
> Consider, for example, running a program with file descriptor 2
> closed. The next file the program opens will be assigned that
> descriptor. If something then causes the program to write to (what it
> thinks is) the standard error stream, that output will, instead, go to
> the other file which had been opened, probably corrupting that file. A
> malicious user can easily make messes this way; when setuid programs
> are involved, the potential consequences are worse.

Taken from https://lwn.net/Articles/347815/

PS Check [`svn blame` for this part of code](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/blame/head/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/cmdline.c?line=114). It has a [log message](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/commit/r850893/head/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/cmdline.c) that describes the purpose of these checks.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I kind of understand it a bit more but still coudn't grasp the idea.
Running a program with file descriptor 2 closed. What does file descriptor stderr closed mean ? As long as I know there is only close() function in unix that closes any file descriptor. So how does a program close stderr ? And let's say we closed it, how does the next file we open get assigned to stderr. I'm not an expert but I don't know how a program can open a file with stderr. Can you elaborate that part a bit more ?

Comment: @Zer0day I suggest that you contact the [dev@ Subversion mailing list](https://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html#dev-ml) asking for the exact purpose of this code and what kind of issues it is designed to prevent.